# Asp.net web api MVC

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I want to add another query in this method which is

> select product_name from product where product id=+id

but it gives error because list have sales_line table.. how to resolve this? can anyone help me?

```
public List<sales_line> Get(int id)
    {
        using (project_smartEntities entities = new project_smartEntities())
        {
            entities.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            return entities.sales_lines.SqlQuery("Select * from sales_line where sales_id=" + id).ToList<sales_line>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: There isn't enough info to answer your question. Add more code, the error you receive, and explain better your needings

Comment: i want to apply query in which i select * from sales table and product_name from product table.. the issue is in list, which have sales table so it gives error because it don't have product table

Comment: Still not clear on whether you are trying to JOIN to the product table or you have an issue mapping your results into the model. At a minimum edit your question and show the models involved (sales_line, product) and paste the exact error message in.

Answer (score -1):

you con use union sql

```
Select *,'a' as type_select from sales_line
union all
Select *,'b' as type_select from sales_line1
```

Comment: it gives unexpected code error on product table which is not found bcz of this line ToList<sales_line>();